# Combining objects in an array by common keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a dataset, an array of objects, I need to combine by a common key (Date) and then merge the UserName as the key for the UserScore. 
I am planning to graph this data with d3 and have the solution using some of d3's methods but would like to write it with vanilla JS. Here is a sample of the raw data

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 00:00:00 UTC",
    "UserName": "user1",
    "UserScore": "39"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 00:00:00 UTC",
    "UserName": "user2",
    "UserScore": "11"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 00:00:00 UTC",
    "UserName": "user3",
    "UserScore": "4"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 01:01:01 UTC",
    "UserName": "user1",
    "UserScore": "57"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 01:01:01 UTC",
    "UserName": "user2",
    "UserScore": "1"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 01:01:01 UTC",
    "UserName": "user3",
    "UserScore": "42"
  }
]
```

Here is my desired output

```
   {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 00:00:00 UTC",
    "user1": "39",
    "user2": "11",
    "user3": "4"
   },
   {
    "Date": "2019-05-02 01:01:01 UTC",
    "user1": "57",
    "user2": "1",
    "user3": "42"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to group them.

```js
const arr = [ { "Date": "2019-05-02 00:00:00 UTC", "UserName": "user1", "UserScore": "39" }, { "Date": "2019-05-02 00:00:00 UTC", "UserName": "user2", "UserScore": "11" }, { "Date": "2019-05-02 00:00:00 UTC", "UserName": "user3", "UserScore": "4" }, { "Date": "2019-05-02 01:01:01 UTC", "UserName": "user1", "UserScore": "57" }, { "Date": "2019-05-02 01:01:01 UTC", "UserName": "user2", "UserScore": "1" }, { "Date": "2019-05-02 01:01:01 UTC", "UserName": "user3", "UserScore": "42" } ]

const res = arr.reduce((ac,{Date,UserName,UserScore}) => {
  ac[Date] = ac[Date] || {Date};
  ac[Date][UserName] = UserScore;
  return ac;
},{})

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Almost exactly what I am looking for, one issue is I now have an object of nested objects. Changing the initial value to an array I still have nested objects, any way to have each object its own item of the array using this solution?

Comment: @wesellboxes Oh yeah sorry I forgot part. See the updated answer. You can use `Object.values()`. Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied